# populate jquery ui datepicker datefield from alternative field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I always wondered how you do this. I save the value of the alternative field of my datepicker to database (in MySQL date format). If I get that from the db I can populate the altField with it. But the actual datepicker field is still empty. I would have to get it formatted from the db and populate that field too. But shouldn't the datepicker do this? Is it possible?

```
//html
// {$dbDate.expires} = '2016-01-01'
// {$dbDate.expires_formatted} = '01.01.2016'
<input type="hidden" name="expires" value="{$dbDate.expires}">
<input type="text" class="datepicker"> //should display the value "01.01.2016"
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="{$dbDate.expires_formatted}"> //this is what I currently do instead

//js
.datepicker({
    altField : $(document).find('input[name="expires"]'),
    altFormat : "yy-mm-dd"
 }, $.datepicker.regional['someRegional']);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkxcqub6/ - This fiddle shows how it should work. Except here you will see the problem is the date is not formatted correctly initially (because the format from the db is different from the format displayed). Also the selected date in the datepicker is the current date not the date that comes from the db.

https://jsfiddle.net/mkxcqub6/1/ - This fiddle shows what I'm doing right now. I get the date in two formats from the db. One as MySQL can handle it and in the user defined format. That way the datepicker shows the date as selected too.

Comment: I think you mean to read the value from `'input[name="expires"]'` into either `setDate` or `defaultDate` so that when the users goes to select a date, it starts with the expires date. Or am I misunderstanding the goal?

Comment: no not quite. if you select a date in the calendar that date is displayed in the format you choose in the input field. but if you save the alternative field to the database you only have the date in that format.
now if you get the date from the db you want to display the date set in the input field in the correct format (not the format saved to the db)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise doing this via `setDate` and `defaultDate`. See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ht87Lvqv/

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="expires" value="2012-06-01">
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input class="date-picker" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var $inp = $("input[name='expires']").val();
  var YY = parseInt($inp.substring(0, 4));
  var MM = parseInt($inp.substring(5, 7)) - 1;
  var DD = parseInt($inp.substring(9,11));
  var myDate = $inp != "" ? new Date(YY, MM, DD) : new Date();
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: myDate
  }).datepicker("setDate", myDate);
});
```

Remember that `Date` uses a 0 - 11 month array.

**EDIT**

After your update, it's still a little unclear how you want to use the fields, but I hope this helps make the alternate field more clear:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ht87Lvqv/1/

**HTML**

```
Hidden: <input type="text" class="hidden" name="expires" value="2016-01-01">
Normal: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="current">
Formatted: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="formatted" value="01.01.2016">
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var $inp = $("input[name='expires']").val();
  var YY = parseInt($inp.substring(0, 4));
  var MM = parseInt($inp.substring(5, 7)) - 1;
  var DD = parseInt($inp.substring(9,11));
  var myDate = $inp != "" ? new Date(YY, MM, DD) : new Date();
  $("#current").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: myDate,
    altField : $("#formatted"),
    altFormat : "dd.mm.yy"
  }).datepicker("setDate", myDate);
});
```

When you now pick a date, it places an alternately formatted date to the `#formatted` field. I strongly advise using IDs for your fields.

Comment: Yes. That is pretty ugly. What if you change the format? Or imagine different display formats depending on the language of the user.

Comment: But the datepicker already knows what format you save to and what format you want to display. It already has methods to change the format, so it should transfer the alt-field back to the display format too in my point of view. But this seems not possible. So I wonder why cause this seems like the normal use case, or I am doing something really wrong. But what else would the alt-field be for then anyway?

Comment: @4485670 you could create the dateFormat string outside of the function. I think I see what you're saying, where you want one field to display a specific format and then an alternative field for the DB right?

Comment: Yes, the normal field format is for display on the page. The alt-Field format is saved to db.

Comment: @4485670 can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I think it is against stack rules. Also as stuff is saved and fetched from db that wouldn't make much sense. It wouldn't be much more than the code sample above.

Comment: @4485670 It is not against SO rules. Use example data for your example code that shows the specific issue you're encountering. Your OP does not include enough data to properly clarify the issue. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have edited my initial post, does it make the issue more clear?

Comment: @4485670 yes that does help! I will edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: Sorry but that is not how it should work at all. There should just be ONE datepicker with one (the formatted) date displayed. And that date should be saved in format "yy-mm-dd" to the database. I tried to make a jsfiddle, but currently I can't get the datepicker to work there as expected.

Comment: Follow the link for one of the ones I offered, and use the "Fork" option across the top. This will create a new jsfiddle, with the current code, and all the extended JQuery & UI needs.